# How do i get all console logs to a discord text/embed message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How do i get all console logs to a discord text/embed message ?
I tried reading node.js documentations for console but couldn't find or understand information in general

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really after...console.logging is not something used by Embeds as a code flow. Are you asking for internal debugging information from Embeds, or are you asking to see the content of what you're sending via embed, before it gets sent as a message to discord?

Comment: @G-Force i'm for all content in the console to be sent to an embed/text message

Comment: you want to redirect all console messages to embeds/discord-messages?  Why not just make embed messages instead of your console code?

Comment: ... i'm dumb for not thinking that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying to get all messages of a particular channel?
you can do this like this code

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("Your channel ID");
channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then(messages => {
  console.log(`Fetched ${messages.size} messages Successfully`);
  messages.forEach(message => 
     console.log(message.content))
})
```

you can only fetch maximum 100 message at a time